# Convergence of Series Whose Terms are Defined Recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

My recursively defined sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is given trough

$$a_1 = 1, \quad a_2=\frac{1}{2}\quad a_{n+2}=a_{n}a_{n+1}\quad \text{for } n\geq1$$

and I have to show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$

converges.

---

**I have 4 questions to my approach(es) I did to deal with that:**

1. I noticed that $a_n$ can be represented as $$a_n = 2^{-f_{n-1}}$$
   whereas $f_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. For this claim I did this proof by induction:

   $$ n=1: a_1 = 1 = 2^0 = 2^{f_0} = 2^{-f_0} = 2^{-f_{1-1}} \\
    n=2: a_2 = \frac{1}{2} = 2^{-1} = 2^{-f_1} =  2^{-f_{2-1}}$$
   and by multiplying the premises $A(n)$ and $A(n+1)$ in order to get $A(n+2)$
   $$"n+1\to n+2":\quad a_n \cdot a_{n+1}  = 2^{-f_{n-1}} \cdot 2^{-f_n} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\\  a_{n+2} = a_n \cdot a_{n+1} = 2^{-f_{n-1}} \cdot 2^{-f_n} = 2^{-(f_n + f_{n-1})} = 2^{-f_{n+1}}.$$
   ...is that valid?
2. Given that $a_n = 2^{-f_{n-1}}$ is true I proceeded with the ratio test
   $$q := \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{2^{-f_{n}}}{2^{-f_{n-1}}}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{f_{n-1}}}{2^{f_{n}}} =\\
    = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{f_{n} - f_{n-1}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{(f_{n-2} + f_{n-1}) - f_{n-1}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{f_{n-2}}} < 1.$$
   Is that sufficient to show the convergence? Follow-up question: given the $a_n = 2^{-f_{n-1}}$ term - is there a better way than this ratio test to show convergence of $\sum a_n$ now that I have this representation?
3. Another approach would be to find a sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with
   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n < \infty \quad\wedge\quad |b_n| > |a_n|\quad\forall n\geq1.$$
   For what it's worth I struggle to find such a series - am I missing something? Is there something immediate that should come to mind? $a_n$ and $b_n$ have to be zero sequences, how can I do the estimate in its recursively defined form?
4. Another "please correct me if I'm wrong"-question: I did an approach where I proved that $a_{n+1}< a_{n}$ for all $n\geq1$ (which is similar to question 1:

   $$n=1:\quad a_1 = 1 \geq \frac{1}{2} = a_2\\
   n=2: a_3 = a_1a_2 = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2},\quad\therefore a_2 = \frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2} = a_3$$
   and
   $$"n+1 \to n+2":\quad a_n \cdot a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n+2} \Longleftrightarrow\\
   a_{n+2} = a_n \cdot a_{n+1} \geq a_{n+1} \cdot a_{n+2} =  a_{(n+1)+2} = a_{n+3}$$
   respectively) and after that I did the ratio test
   $$q := \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_n a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|a_{n}\right| \stackrel{*}{<} 1.$$
   (with (*) denoting that $a_{n+1}<a_{n}$ and $a_2 <1$). Is that a sufficient answer to my problem?

   ---

### ...thank you so much, guys!

Comment: Note that $a_n\leq{2^{2-n}}$.

Answer (score -1):

I would greatly prefer your approach no.3 because such series are actually easy to find. One example is the geometric series with ratio 1/2 (up to an initial "stutter" term which is easy to discard).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As I wrote, I struggle to show that... which approach shows $\left|b_n\right| > \left|a_n\right|$ for every single $n\geq 1$?

Comment: Use the geometric series with ratio 1/2 multiplied by 4 (to make up for the mess in the first two terms): $a_n<4.2^{-n}$ This is the same as saying that the $n$-th Fibonacci number is greater than $n-2.$ BTW you do not actually need to show it for every single $n,$ convergence is already guaranteed if you can show it for sufficiently large $n.$